# Refresh content in Tab of TabActivity

Tags: android

I have a tab with an intent as its content:

```
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("Chart")              
            .setContent(lineChartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
```

How is it possible to refresh the content of a tab? I am thinking of a method like

```
tab.refreshContent()
```

or similar. Background is: My intent contains a graph and I want to repaint this graph upon click of a button while the tab remains selected. Thanks.

Comment: thinking the same question right now

Comment: Same question. Any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

best way i know

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

it refresh all the Activity